# OneToMany doesn't save changes

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I have a oneToMany - ManyToOne relation between two entities.

When editing on the Departement edit page (owning side, ManyToOne), changes will be saved into the departement table,
but editing from the Utilisateur edit page (inverse side, OneToMany), changes won't be saved into the Departement table.

Can someone exmplain me why it's not working?

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Entity/Utilisateur.php**</kbd>

```
class Utilisateur implements UserInterface, \Serializable {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Departement", mappedBy="commercial")
     */
    private $departements;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->departements=new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Departement $departement
     * @return Utilisateur
     */
    public function addDepartement(\AppBundle\Entity\Departement $departement)
    {
        $this->departements[] = $departement;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Departement $departement
     */
    public function removeDepartement(\AppBundle\Entity\Departement $departement)
    {
        $this->departements->removeElement($departement);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getDepartements()
    {
        return $this->departements;
    }
}
```

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Entity/Departement.php**</kbd>

```
class Departement {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur", inversedBy="departements")
     */
    private $commercial;

    /**
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur $commercial
     * @return Departement
     */
    public function setCommercial(\AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur $commercial=null) {
        $this->commercial=$commercial;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
     */
    public function getCommercial() {
        return $this->commercial;
    }
}
```

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Form/Utilisateur/Edit3dhType.php**</kbd>

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('departements', EntityType::class, array(
        'class'=>Departement::class,
        'expanded'=>true,
        'multiple'=>true
    ));
}
```

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Controller/UtilisateurController.php**</kbd>

```
/**
 * @Route("/dashboard/utilisateurs/edit-{id}", name="security_edit_user")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Utilisateur $utilisateur
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Utilisateur $utilisateur) {
    $logo=$utilisateur->getLogo();
    if($utilisateur->getLogo() !== null) {
        $utilisateur->setLogo(new File($this->getParameter('dir_picto').$logo));
    }

    $form=$this->createForm(Edit3dhType::class, $utilisateur, array(
        'action'=>$this->generateUrl('security_edit_user', array('id'=>$utilisateur->getId())),
        'method'=>'POST',
    ));

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        if($utilisateur->getLogo() !== null) {
            $utilisateur->setLogo($this->container->get('service.upload')->uploadPicto($utilisateur->getLogo()));
        } else {
            $utilisateur->setLogo($logo);
        }

        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('security/edit.html.twig', array(
        'user'=>$this->getUser(),
        'utilisateur'=>$utilisateur,
        'form'=>$form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Is logo file entity? If yeah, then you're doing the whole process wrong, because you can't save the files in DB, you must move it to folder and save path only. I just don't see the whole entity, wondering.... Could you edit code and add full parts of setters / entity field for this logo?

Comment: @revengeance `$utilisateur->setLogo($this->container->get('service.upload')->uploadPicto($utilisateur->getLogo()));`. Also, the file isn't the problem here... It's working fine and as it should. It can also be null. Out of topic, but will still update a bit for some getters and setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... Thanks to TEDx who hinted me some docs, after hours of searchs and reading, tons of dumps and a small chat with a bear... I came to understand the following.

First, Doctrine seems to only check data on the owning side of the relation. Meaning that it won't handle things if done from the inverse side.

Second, related to the first problem, as I'm trying to do things on the inverse side, Doctrine won't set `departement.commercial` in the form array collection. Thus, finding no differences with the data in the table, it doesn't make any query.

Last, Doctrine won't detect any unchecked entry in the form (so setting `departement.commercial` to `NULL`).

Below the solution I came up with. It apply for the inverse side of OneToMany/ManyToOne relations. And with some tweak can also be used for ManyToMany relations.

<kbd>**src/AppBundle/Controller/UtilisateurController.php**</kbd>

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Utilisateur $utilisateur) {
    //Save pre submit data
    $preSubmitDepartement=$utilisateur->getDepartements()->toArray();

    $form=$this->createForm(UtilisateurType::class, $utilisateur, array(
        'action'=>$this->generateUrl('security_edit_user', array('id'=>$utilisateur->getId())),
        'method'=>'POST',
        'utilisateur'=>$utilisateur,
    ));

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        //Get post submit data
        $postSubmitDepartement=$utilisateur->getDepartements()->toArray();

        //Keep only IDs for pre and post submit data
        /** @var Departement $v */
        foreach($preSubmitDepartement as $k=>$v) {
            $preSubmitDepartement[$k]=$v->getId();
        }
        /** @var Departement $v */
        foreach($postSubmitDepartement as $k=>$v) {
            $postSubmitDepartement[$k]=$v->getId();
        }

        //Find removed IDs
        $prePostSubmitDifference=array_map('unserialize', array_diff(array_map('serialize',$preSubmitDepartement), array_map('serialize',$postSubmitDepartement)));

        //Fetch related Departement entries
        $departements=$em->getRepository(Departement::class)->findBy(array('id'=>array_merge($postSubmitDepartement, $prePostSubmitDifference)));

        //setCommercial to $utilisateur or null
        /** @var Departement $departement */
        foreach($departements as $departement) {
            if(in_array($departement->getId(), $postSubmitDepartement)) {
                $departement->setCommercial($utilisateur);
            } else if(in_array($departement->getId(), $prePostSubmitDifference)) {
                $departement->setCommercial(null);
            }
        }

        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('security/edit.html.twig', array(
        'user'=>$user,
        'utilisateur'=>$utilisateur,
        'form'=>$form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Now I can set `departement.conseiller` from the inverse side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that the entity is managed by Doctrine. You can do this by calling the `persist` method with your object as the argument (`$em->persist($utilisateur)`).

While you retrieved the object via Doctrine, it is already managed, so Doctrine might be unaware of the fact that it should also persist object via the OneToMany relationship. As @Dirk mentioned, setting the cascade operation would certainly make a difference. You can add that to the `Utilisateur` class like so:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Departement", mappedBy="commercial", cascade={"persist"})
```

You should receive an exception when you're trying to persist an entity (via a relation) that is not managed by Doctrine. So it's strange that you aren't getting one...

Check if the form is actually creating a `Department` instance and adding it to the `Utilisateur` class (you're not specifying a type when adding the "department" field to the form).

Comment: Not related, I'm editing, not creating... Entity already exists

Comment: Editing or creating makes no difference, you need to tell Doctrine that it must manage the object (by calling the `persist` method on the object you want to create/update), otherwise your `flush` call won't make any difference. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities

Comment: Tried, changed nothing, still not working. With Symfony/DC2, you only need to persist (INSERT) when you create your entity. If you're editing, you don't need to use persist, the UPDATE action will be done before the flush. Symfony will handle everything just fine when it will read your entity object and "notice" that it's an existing entry.

Comment: From your link (what I said in simpler terms): `If X is a new entity, it becomes managed`, `If X is a preexisting managed entity, it is ignored by the persist operation`. Thus, using persist won't change anything if entity already exist.

Comment: Guess I missed the part where you retrieve the object from Doctrine (in the `editAction` method) which makes it managed. My bad! The comment Dirk posted is almost correct, but the `cascade`operation should be on the `Utilisateur` side (which is the entity that you are updating). Have you tried that? I think it's strange that you didn't get an exception. If Doctrine notices that you are trying to persist an object via a relation, it should tell you...

Comment: Seen yes... Checking things. About the type of Departement, if you leave it null, it mean that Symfony will keep the original type (thus Departement entity type here).

Comment: It's still not persisting... Can't seems to access the form profiler page after submitting. Checked query, only Utilisateur is seens in the transaction.

Comment: Could you try running the code with a new `Utilisateur` object that has the `$department` variable set with a newly created instance of the `Department` class (just place that in the constructor of the `Utilisateur` class)? Wild guess: have you run `cache:clear`? I've noticed sometimes Symfony has trouble updating the annotations.

Comment: Can't with a new user. First Departement entries are sets, there won't be more or less later. Second, it's not allowed to attribute one or more Departement to Utilisateur when persisting a new one. Only possible when editing one. (meant to be like this)

Comment: Check my own answer. This is what I was looking for. ;)

Comment: Great to hear you found a solution! Just a heads up: using serialize/unserialize is vulnerable for object injection (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection). You might want to investigate using `array_udiff` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php)  with a custom function to compare your `Department` instances :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your cascading operation with `cascade={"persist"}` like this:

```
class Departement {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Utilisateur", inversedBy="departements", cascade={"persist"} )
     */
    private $commercial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your FormType, you need to do the following.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)     {

 $builder->add('departements', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'=> DepartmentType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
            'by_reference' => false // calls addDepartement / removeDepartement on parent(Utilisateur) automatically
        ));}
```

For Info Read : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: I fear that it's not what I need. `Departement` table is already filled with entries. Second point, I can't test this as it's not letting me use `multiple`

Comment: Yeah, totally not what I need. It's displaying a full DepartementType form under my user. Not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you please show me the submitted form in your profiler?
We can then check the view format and normalized format. 
This will solve your problem

Comment: Well, I sorta found out a solution, applying it before posting my answer. The problem isn't about the view format. But what happen when for is submitted. The `Departement` part of the form is a select with multiple allowed (https://ibb.co/fCXz39). While reading a lot of doc, with the first one hinted by TEDx, I found out that Symfony doesn't really handle inverse side. It only check data on the owning side. I'm still checking a few things, but I will post my answer on this matter in the day

Comment: Check my own answer. This is what I was looking for. ;)